# How to make the drop down open at the position of selected value in angular?

Tags: angular, dropdown, html-select

I made a drop-down in Angular using select. I want the selected value to be visible in the drop down the first time I click on it, so I don't have to scroll all the way down. For eg I made this dropdown showing years from 1950 to 2020. I want the drop down to open with the default selected year(2010 in my case) visible in it. How can I achieve it?

...

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let year of years" [selected]="year == 2010">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

...

Comment: please provide a stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't opposed to using Angular Material, `mat-select` will open the select from the chosen value.

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select value="2010">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">{{year}}</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: It would mess up with the css in rest of the page.